# How do you compile a flask app with cython?

Tags: python, flask, cython

I have a Python flask app that I need to compile using cython.
Following [this guide](https://medium.com/@xpl/protecting-python-sources-using-cython-dcd940bb188e), I can compile a simple python application, but when I do the same thing to a simple flask app:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

It seems to compile fine, but when I try to run it, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

When I try to run main.py.

My compile.py looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ext_modules = [ 
    Extension("app",  ["app.py"]),
]
setup(
    name = 'My Test Website',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

My main.py looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from app import main
main()
```

Does flask use some features that can't be compiled? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What is `run.py`? There is indeed no name `main` in your `app` module, so that is expected.

Comment: Ah, so `main.py` is really `run.py`? You can't import `main` from app without compiling with Cython *either*. What should `main()` **do**?

Comment: Side note: there is no point in compiling just `app.py`; the Flask library (including dependencies such as Werkzeug) does most of the work and is not going to be compiled. For performance with Flask, pick a good deployment strategy and optimise for caching and CDN delivery of static resources, the network is the first bottleneck you need to optimise for.

Comment: Tip: if the point is to gain performance, consider running your flask application with PyPy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't define a `main()` function in `app.py`, so `from app import main` fails, yes.

You could just import the `app` Flask object, and call the `run()` method on that:

```
from app import app

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

Not that you should use this in production deployments. You'd instead instruct a production-ready WSGI server to use the `app` object in the `app` module as the WSGI application. See the [Flask deployment documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/).

Comment: When dealing with a simple python app that wasn't flask, I didn't define a main() function either, and it worked with cython. Cython appeared to automatically generate a main() function. It didn't with flask. Guess it works different here. Thanks

Comment: Now I'm running into "takes no keyword arguments" errors. To fix these, apparently, I need to set always_allow_keywords to True, but I'm not sure where to do that in my compile.py. Anyone know?

Comment: @John: `always_allow_keywords` is a directive, see the [*How to set directives* documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html#how-to-set-directives).

Comment: The link appears to use cython to compile a python module in a completely different way than my source link. It calls the cythonize() function, which I'm not calling. I'm not sure how to integrate the cythonize() call into my compile.py, or if I even need to.

Comment: @John: that page shows you how to use `cytonize` to set the `extensions` attribute. All that `cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},` does is replace `extensions = ...` with `extensions = cytonize(...)`, really.